# How to work with [Required] attribute & Model State Validation within Web Api Put

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

Currently I am facing, a problem, when try to call Web Api put method from MVC Api Client, lets describe my code structure bellow

**Test Model (Web Api end)**

```
 public sealed class Test    
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Web Api PUT Method**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(string token, IEnumerable<Test> data)
{
     [...]
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

**Web Api Custom Filter**

```
 public sealed class ValidateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext"></param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Call from Web Api Client**

```
async System.Threading.Tasks.Task VerifiedFAccount()
        {
            using (var client = GetHttpClient())
            {
                var url = string.Concat("/api/Verfication", "?token=", token);

                var data = new SampleTest { Id = 1, Name = "xxx" };
                var temp = new List<SampleTest>();
                temp.Add(data);
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync
                <IEnumerable<SampleTest>>(url, temp).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {


                    }
                }
            }
```

Client code unable to execute Api call (Even I placed the debug point within Web Api Put method, unable to hit the debug point) & always got the bellow error response

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?STpcRGV2QXJlYUxvY2FsXENPTVBBTlkgLSBQU1AgUFJPSkVDVFNcRS1BdXRob3JpdHkgLSBBdXN0cmVsaXlhXFNvdXJjZUNvbnRyb2xcVHJ1bmtcMDYgRGVjIDIwMTNcRS1BdXRob3JpdHkuQXBpIC0gMjAxM1xFYXV0aG9yaXR5LldlYi5BcGkuUHJlc2VudGF0aW9uTGF5ZXJcYXBpXFNtc2ZBY2NvdW50VmVyZmljYXRpb24=?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 11:23:27 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  Content-Length: 2179
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

But when I remove `[Required]` from **Test Model (Web Api end)**. Then above described client code execute successfully.

Please tell me what is the reason of this kind of confusing behavior ?

Comment: Why do you send an array of `Test` to the service? In some of my projects it was quite useful to implement an ITraceWriter and register it in order to find the reason for similar errors (see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing might be because of the behaviour of the default configuration when it comes to data validation. You have a `Required` attributed on a non-nullable type and since `int` can't be null, it will always have a value (the default of `0`) if the incoming request does not provide the value.

In these cases, the model validator will throw an exception because it doesn't make sense to have a `Required` attribute on a property that can't be null.

The straightforward way you would be to change a setting on your MVC application:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
    .AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

This will get rid of the error that is thrown by the framework. This introduce the problem that you will get a value of `0` even when the request does not include the property. It makes more sense to have your integer be of `Nullable<int>`. The `Required` attribute will be able to handle a `null` value and you will know whether or not the incoming request included the property

```
public sealed class Test    
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;` is good to know, but actual problem is not `public int?` in my case. I converted my Project from 4 to 4.5 and the problem is gone. Previous project with framework 4, malfunctioning some how. (surprisingly but it is true)